# can I use PL_indy on android codetyphon?

Tags: android, indy, lazarus

Hello I come with a question I am making an application that needs to use indy but when compiling the project using the indy component throws me an error like this post www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/fo...build-android-ct-5-0 but this item takes much time have been posted if it is possible to create an android application using the indy components since I need it for my application thank you for your answer or suggestion"

Comment: The link you provided is not valid. What is the ACTUAL error you are seeing? What environment are you using to create your app with? Is there a reason why you are relying on a third-party repackaging of Indy instead of using the official Indy packages?  What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to create a proxy with indy and I have all the source code but it is too long to post it, and the problem is similar to this link  [link](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/forums/android/2949-crossbuild-android-ct-5-0)happens while compiling the application, the ide that I use is CODETYPHON since what I read is an ide that uses pascal and is cross-platform applications but it does not work appreciate your response thanks for answering is the first almost nobody knows of the topic

Comment: adding to the ves PL_INDY is = indy indy server Pack original packages

Comment: I don't know anything about CodeTyphon. Indy officially supports only Delphi/C++Builder and FreePascal/Lazarus IDE environments. And although Indy does support Android, it is currently only set up to do so for Delphi/C++Builder, not for other IDEs yet, as it relies on Embarcadero's RTL support for accessing Android's Posix APIs.

Comment: If PilotLogic provides its own version of the Indy packages for CodeTyphon (Indy does not provide official packages for CodeTyphon), then it is PilotLogic's responsibility to make sure Indy compiles correctly within CodeTyphon's environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply I have a last question I hope, what I've seen codetyphon has an interface very similar to lazarus if uninstall components by default which brings codetyphon I install official packages of indy officer lazarus? When compiling or that I recommend you that aside from using jetty or lazarus since I have not been able to compile for android at codetypon only lazarus but this problem I can not compile for indy

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: He asked that another alternative I can use apart from codetyphon that may indy that is just or lazarus which is compiled more difficult for my excuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already have the answer to my problem I had commented and this is remy lebau has reason indy can work in android using lazarus and the official version of indy in his page can download you INDY working on ANDROID, but rather if it is not can use codetyphon since it is not compatible and will give errors trying to compile then for that solution is to download lazarus4android and follow step by step in this tutorial is the best tutorial I've found it more explained and share them in case anyone has the same problem as I

http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=22414.0

GOOD LOCK